# Lumen class Artisan not found

Tags: php, lumen

I am working on an Lumen project.

I try to use

```
Artisan::call('my-command')
```

But PHP says me the class Artisan is not defined.

I have already enable Facade with the following command :

```
$app->withFacades();
```

So the Log class works after **use Log;** line.
I have already add the **use Artisan** line.
But it doesn't works.

The following command works in CLI:

```
php artisan my-command
```

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error occured because I use a wrong **use sentence** :

```
use Artisan; // Doesn't work
```

I must use this absolute **use sentence** :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
```

I hope it will be helpful